# clojure - No divisors

Tags: clojure

Going off that divides?, I now need a defn(no divisors?). I have created something close to the answer however it is not outputting what I require. maybe you could help again and would be much appreciated.

I think I will probably need to wrap the divides? function in an anonymous function so that you can pass in the value of n.

```
(defn divides? [div num]
  (zero? (mod num div)))
```

Below code has the problem

```
(defn no-divisors? [n]
 (->> (range 2 n)
 (take-while #(< (* % %) n))
 (filter (partial divides? n))
empty?))

///current output///
(no-divisors? 9)
=> true
(no-divisors? 7)
=> true
///current output///

/// expected output///
(no-divisors? 9)
=> false
(no-divisors? 7)
 => true
 /// expected output///
```

any help would be much to solve this would be great.

Comment: So you're basically trying to find out if a number is a prime number? Every number always has as divisors itself and 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(defn no-divisors? [n]
  (->> (range 2 n)
       (filter #(divides? % n))
       empty?))
```